# How to format a date in a Pandas dataframe column with a certain date format such as YYYY-MMM-DD

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am able to convert the date value to a Pandas datetime object, however I am not able to specify the format of that date without there being an error.

The two formats I want to use are `YYYY-MMM-DD` which is `format='%Y%b%d'` and `YYYY-MM-DD` which is `format='%Y%m%d'`

However when I try and use the following code, I get an error:

```
def convert_date(x):
    x = x.strip()
    x = pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y%b%d')
    return x
```

Comment: "An error" is not helpful.  Please include the complete error message in your post.

Comment: Do you mean `%Y-%b-%d` instead of `%Y%b%d`?